# convert info to Pacific Time Zone

Tags: php, datetime

I have an php variable that outputs the following:

`18:00 Denver Airport (DEN), Terminal`

I want to convert that time to Los Angeles time but I do not know where to begin.

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that your PHP variable contains the string `"18:00 (6:00 pm) Denver Airport (DEN), Terminal"`? Do you have any more information than that available such as the date and timezone you're converting from?

Comment: Note: Daylight savings means date is important for timezones. You'll also have to parse out the `18:00` part.

Comment: @Phil yes my variable contains that entire line...